# Java Program that Accepts an Input Word and Output any Anagrams Found in an Imported .txt File?

Tags: java, eclipse, anagram

For an assignment in a computer science course I'm taking this semester, I need to build a java program that imports a .txt file of words, accepts a word as an input, scrambles the input word, then outputs a list of anagrams (i.e. words equal in length to the scrambled word that use the exact same letters) for the scramble. The program also needs to be able to loop, such that a user can input a new word after they receive an output an repeat the program or input a specific character to terminate the program.

I'm still pretty new to programming and coding and the like, so there are still a lot of concepts and tricks I still don't know or understand yet.

I was able to look-up or otherwise figure-out most of the necessary code for the project and have it mostly assembled already, but there are a few things that I still need to do but don't really know how:

1) I need to separate the different sections of code into multiple methods, but I'm not sure how I should go about separate, organize, or access them from the main method.

2) I need to create a loop for the program, but I haven't found a way for the loop to work properly; I either get caught in an infinite loop or there's no loop at all.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Anagrams {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Welcome to X's Anagram Solver!");
        System.out.println("Please enter a word to scramble to continue, or enter 'n' or 'N' to quit:");

        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Scanner Kbin = new Scanner(new File("dict.txt"))){
            while (Kbin.hasNext()) {
                words.add(Kbin.next());
            }
        }
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (String str : words) {
            char[] temp = str.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(temp);
            String key = new String(temp).toLowerCase();
            if (map.get(key) != null) {
                map.get(key).add(str.toLowerCase());
            }
            else {
                List<String> anagramList = new ArrayList<>();
                anagramList.add(str);
                map.put(key, anagramList);
            }
        }

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = input.next();
        char[] key = str.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(key);
        str = new String(key).toLowerCase();
        if (!map.containsKey(str)) {
            System.out.println("The input word was not found in our dictionary file.");
            System.out.println("Please enter a different word to scramble to continue, or enter 'n' or 'N' to quit:");
        }
        else if (map.get(str).size() != 1) {
            System.out.println("All words found in '" + str + "':");
            for (String p : map.get(str)) {
                System.out.println(p + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("You may enter a new word to scramble, or enter 'n' or 'N' to quit:");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No anagrams for this word were found.");
            System.out.println("You may enter a new word to scramble, or enter 'n' or 'N' to quit:");
        }
        str = input.next();

        System.out.println("Thank you for using X's Anagram Solver!");
        System.out.println("Have a nice day!");

        input.close();  
        }

    }
```

For clarity, if a user were to input the word "share" for the program, the word would get scrambled and stored into it's canonical form (letters stored in sorted order). The program would then determine whether the word "share" is present in the .txt file and whether any other words share the same letters. The output is then a list of words in the .txt that have the same letters as "share" like so:

- hares
- hears
- share
- shear

How should I separate the different sections of my code into methods? And how can I implement the loop once I've done so? I'm genuinely at a loss here and just need some guidance on this and would really appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on what I should do.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me with this!

P.S. I'm sorry but I don't have a means of providing the .txt file used in the code, but it is basically just a long, alphabetical list of words.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this oO

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class Anagrams {

   Map<String, List<String>> map;

   Anagrams(){
      map  = getAnagrams();
   }

    private List<String> getWords(){
        List<String> words=new ArrayList<>();
        try (Scanner Kbin = new Scanner(new File("dict.txt"))){
            while (Kbin.hasNext()) {
                words.add(Kbin.next());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("couldnt find dict.txt");
        }
        return words;
    }

    private Map<String,List<String>> getAnagrams(){
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        List<String> words = getWords();
        for (String str : words) {
            String key = sorted(str);
            if (map.get(key) != null) {
                map.get(key).add(str.toLowerCase());
            }
            else {
                List<String> anagramList = new ArrayList<>();
                anagramList.add(str);
                map.put(key, anagramList);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    public String sorted(String unsorted){
        char[] key = unsorted.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(key);
        return new String(key).toLowerCase();

    }

    public void evaluate(String str){
        str=sorted(str);
        if (!map.containsKey(str)) {
            System.out.println("The input word was not found in our dictionary file.");
            System.out.println("Please enter a different word to scramble to continue, or enter 'n' or 'N' to quit:");
        }
        else if (map.get(str).size() != 1) {
            System.out.println("All words found in '" + str + "':");
            for (String p : map.get(str)) {
                System.out.println(p + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("You may enter a new word to scramble, or enter 'n' or 'N' to quit:");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No anagrams for this word were found.");
            System.out.println("You may enter a new word to scramble, or enter 'n' or 'N' to quit:");
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you for using X's Anagram Solver!");
        System.out.println("Have a nice day!");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        System.out.println("Welcome to X's Anagram Solver!");
        System.out.println("Please enter a word to scramble to continue, or enter 'n' or 'N' to quit:");



        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Anagrams anagrams=new Anagrams();

        String str=input.next();
        while(!"exit".equals(str)){

            anagrams.evaluate(str);
            str=input.next();
        }       
        input.close();  
    }

}
```

Comment: i made an exit condition if you type in exit (not sure how you wanted to design that )

Comment: I think this kind of preprocessing is kinda odd though (jsut a feeling) and if you used **regex** you wouldnt need to sort the strings